# CMG biotools - a Perl based tool

Tags: perl

```
sub runBlast {
    # order is preserved !
    for ( my $subject_counter = 0 ; $subject_counter < scalar ( @{$xmlcfg->{sources}[0]->{entry}} ) ; $subject_counter++ ) {
        my $subjectTitle = $INFO{$subject_counter}{title};
        my $subjectSubtitle = $INFO{$subject_counter}{subtitle};
        for ( my $query_counter = 0 ; $query_counter < scalar ( @{$xmlcfg->{sources}[0]->{entry}} ) ; $query_counter++ ) {
            my $queryTitle = $INFO{$query_counter}{title};
            my $querySubtitle = $INFO{$query_counter}{subtitle};
            $tab_h{"$query_counter-$subject_counter"} = $cm->start();
            unless ( $tab_h{"$query_counter-$subject_counter"} ) {
                my $blastreport_scratch = "$scratch/$query_counter-$subject_counter.blastout.gz";
                my $jobid = md5 ( "$scratch/$query_counter.fsa" , "$scratch/$subject_counter.fsa" ) ;
                system "$perl /usr/biotools/indirect/cacher --id='$jobid' --source='$cache_source' -action get > $blastreport_scratch";
                if ( $? != 0 or $clean or -s $blastreport_scratch == 0) {
                    print STDERR "# jobid $jobid not in cache - redoing\n";
                    my $cmd = "$BLASTALL -F 0 -p blastp -d $scratch/$subject_counter.fsa -e 1e-5 -m 7 < $scratch/$query_counter.fsa | $TIGRCUT | gawk '{print \$1\"\\t\"\$2}' | $gzip > $blastreport_scratch";
                    system $cmd;
                    die "# failed at '$cmd'\n" if $? != 0;
                    system "$perl /usr/biotools/indirect/cacher --id=$jobid --source=$cache_source -action put -expire 100 < $blastreport_scratch";
                } else {
                        my $s = -s $blastreport_scratch;
                        print STDERR "# fetched jobid $jobid from cache ( $s bytes)\n";
                }
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
    $cm->wait_all_children; 
}
```

I am completely zero in Perl programming. I had to run this tool called `CMG Biotools` which has been coded in Perl.

I am attaching part of its code here. Can anyone please tell me when `jobid not in cache...redoing` message will be displayed.[code for CMG biotools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55ezB.png)

Comment: Add the code to your question. not as link to a screenshot

Comment: this is the part of the complete code.... the entire code is available @ github .... the link is 
https://github.com/thomasp85/Biotools/blob/master/blastmatrix

Answer (score 0):

Your script, `blastmatrix`, attempts to use an external (to this script) perl tool called "cacher" - `/usr/biotools/indirect/cacher` - passing parameters

- `-action get`
- `--source='$cache_source'`; and
- `--id='$jobid'`

So the script is attemting to retrieve a job with ID `$jobid` from a caching utillity and its failing.  Having failed, the reference to "redoing" appears to be an attempt to run `BLASTALL`, that is `/usr/biotools/blast/bin/blastall`, and then retrys the same cache command.

So, if all you are seeing is the message but the script is working then I'd guess - and that's all I can do - that `BLASTALL` is cleaning up some issue - a unexpected file, a missing file - who knows - and the second attempt at the cache is working.

If it's not working at all, I can only say that it finally fails - which is a different thing from say "the root cause is ..." - when it attempts to use the cacher.

Note - all the above is speculative.

Comment: Thanks for your response Marty. The problem is that the code is working fine when the input say is around 15 to 20 files. Once the number of files increases, "jobid not in cache --redoing" message is displayed in the terminal after some time.

Comment: Are you sure its based solely on the number of files?  Find a definite "fail set" - a bunch of files that fail every time.  Break them up into groups of 10 and run all the groups through the command separately.  If what you say is true, then all the groups should succeed but, if one of the groups fail, and fails repeatedly, you can be sure its something specific to that group of files.  Obviously, you can break the "suspect" group (or groups) down into smaller file sets until you isolate the problem to specific files.